# JSON serialization Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, dynamics-crm-2011

I tried to serialize an appointement in JSON in a custom activity.

Here is the class for Appointment :

```
//<summary>
// Commitment representing a time interval with start/end times and duration.
// </summary>
//
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.EntityLogicalNameAttribute("appointment")]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("CrmSvcUtil", "7.1.0001.3108")]
public partial class Appointment : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

// <summary>
// Default Constructor.
// </summary>
public Appointment() : 
        base(EntityLogicalName)
{
}

public const string EntityLogicalName = "appointment";

public const int EntityTypeCode = 4201;

public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
....
```

And here is the code for the serialization :

```
Entity entity = (Entity) context.InputParameters["Target"];

        ColumnSet csAll = new ColumnSet(true);
        Appointment appointment = (Appointment) service.Retrieve(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id, csAll);

        System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Appointment));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, appointment);
        string jsonNotification = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

And when the activity is executed, I have the following error :

> Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute):
>   SmartwatchMeeting_PushGCM.SmartwatchMeeting:
>   System.Security.SecurityException: The data contract type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5csadsad089],[System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5csadsad089]]'
>   cannot be serialized in partial trust because the member 'key' is not
>   public

I don't understand what I have to add to make it work ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot serialize non-public members of types because the sandbox enforces partial trust, and the serializer leverages reflection.

You can either:

- Switch to `Isolation mode: None` (On-Premise only)
- Write a model class for your data, with only `public` members, and wrap the record. This makes your code larger but works in `Isolation mode: Sandbox`

Comment: I am on Dynamics CRM Online, so it would be the second alternative. Do I have to edit the class generated by CrmSvcUtil ? This line [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()] does not allow serialization ? Thanks

Comment: I'm positive changing the auto-generated code would break it, but I never use it so I can't say for sure. What I suggest is a custom wrapper class.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The thing is that I want to serialize the entire Appointment object which is quite large. What do you think about using Newtonsoft.Json.dll and merge it whith the assembly afterwards ?

Comment: @bidou88 Was it worth the try?

Comment: Yes, I used Newtonsoft.Json and I merged the DLL with ILMerge afterwards. And it works